# Функция отправки формы (Открытие модального окна после отправки)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, инспекция-кода

Доброе утро!

Назрел такой вопрос, как реализовать функцию закрытия формы отправки и вызов другой формы после выполнения метода .POST с помощью ajax. Так же если Вы укажете новичку на его ошибки, буду очень благодарен :)

Есть такое:

1. Валидатор формы:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   var patternmail = /^[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
   var mail = $('#mail');
   var name = $('#firstname');
   var lname = $('#lastname');
   var phone = $('#phone');
   var text = $('#text');

   var allInputs = $('#mail, #firstname, #lastname, #phone, #text');

   $('.alert-danger').hide(1);

   allInputs.on('input', function() {
   var resolution = true;

   if (mail.val() != '') {
     if (mail.val().search(patternmail) == 0) {
       $('#alertmail').hide(1)
       $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
       mail.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
       $('#mail').css('border', 0);
     } else {
       $('#alertmail').show(1)
       $('#mail').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');
       mail.addClass('ok');

       resolution = false;
     }
   } else {
     mail.addClass('error');

     resolution = false;
   }

   if (name.val() != '') {
     if (name.val().length >= 3) {
       $('#alertname').hide(1)
       name.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
       $('#firstname').css('border', 0);
     } else {
       $('#alertname').show(1)
       $('#firstname').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');

       resolution = false;

       name.addClass('ok');
     }
   } else {
     name.addClass('error');

     resolution = false;
   }

   if (lname.val() != '') {
     if (lname.val().length >= 3) {
       $('#alertlname').hide(1)
       lname.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
       $('#lastname').css('border', 0);
     } else {
       $('#alertlname').show(1)
       $('#lastname').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');

       resolution = false;

       lname.addClass('ok');
     }
   } else {
     lname.addClass('error');

     resolution = false;
   }

   if (phone.val() != '') {
     if (phone.val().length >= 9) {
       $('#alertphone').hide(1)
       phone.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
       $('#phone').css('border', 0);
     } else {
       $('#alertphone').show(1)
       $('#phone').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');

       resolution = false;

       phone.addClass('ok');
     }
   } else {
     phone.addClass('error');

     resolution = false;
   }

   if (text.val() != '') {
     if (text.val().length >= 10) {
       $('#alerttext').hide(1)
       text.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
       $('#text').css('border', 0);
     } else {
       $('#alerttext').show(1)
       $('#text').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');

       resolution = false;

       text.addClass('ok');
     }
   } else {
     text.addClass('error');

     resolution = false;
   };

   if (resolution === true) {
     $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
     $('#submit').attr('disabled', '');
   };
     });
     });
   ```
2. Выполнение метода POST, там же прописано открытие модалки - форма отправки пропадает, а вот модалка не открывается.

   ```
   function call() {
     var msg   = $('#formx').serialize();
       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'post.php',
         data: msg,
         success: function(data) {
           $('#contact').hide(1);
           $('#successmodal').show(1);
           $('#successmodal').html(data);
         },
         error:  function(xhr, str){
       alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
         }
       });

   }
   ```

   1. Post.php

   ```
   <strong><?
   $send = $_POST['button'];
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
   $mail = $_POST['mail'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $text = $_POST['text'];
   if ($send != "button"){

       $to = "meowwiza@gmail.com";                 // <- Ваша почта
       $subject = "Письмо с сайта";        // <- Заголовок письма на почте
       $mailheaders .="От: $mail";

       $msg .= "ФИО отправителя: $firstname $lastname\r\n";
       $msg .= "E-mail отправителя: $mail\r\n";
       $msg .= "Телефон: $phone\r\n";
       $msg .= "Сообщение: $text\r\n";

       mail ($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);

       $mess= "Уважаемый $firstname, ваше сообщение было успешно отправленно.";

       echo '<center><p class="text">' . $mess ;

   }

   ?></strong>
   ```

Наша модалка с формой:

```
<div id="contact" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="formx" method="post" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call()">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Обратная связь</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertname" role="alert">Имя введено не корректно.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertlname" role="alert">Введите фамилию.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6"><label class="name">Имя*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><label class="name">Фамилия*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="name" name="firstname" id="firstname"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 hidden-md hidden-lg"><label class="name">Фамилия*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="name" name="lastname" id="lastname"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertmail" role="alert">Введите адрес электронной почты.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="name">Почта*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"><input type="email" class="mail" name="mail" id="mail"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertphone" role="alert">Введите телефон.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="name">Телефон*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" class="mail" name="phone" id="phone"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alerttext" role="alert">Введите сообщение.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="name">Сообщение*</label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"><textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Чтобы было более понятно прикрепляю скриншоты и сам сайт:

http://test.truskahouses.in.ua/pura/

Форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Форма после отправки закрывается и оставляет страницу в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61731/discussion-on-question-by-user234223-----).

Comment: В вопросе очень много кода, непонятно что из него относится к проблеме. Постарайтесь сделать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ссылка на ваш собственный сайт не должна требоваться для понимания. Через неделю ваш сайт поменяется и ссылка станет бесполезной для вопроса. Подробнее: [В: Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83?s=3|0.3432)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ну почему вы такой злобушка, разве инспекция-кода не подразумевает то что код может быть длинным?

Comment: инспекция подразумевает, что в коде нет ошибок, а вы как раз просите ошибки найти. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin ой, всё :c

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, вы банально отменяете отправку сообщения на мыло

```
$send = $_POST['button'];
if ($send != "button"){
```

Попробуйте исправить на

```
$send = $_POST['button'];
if ($send == "button"){
```

Comment: Не-а, теперь даже текст не выводится методом _POST


$mess= "Уважаемый $firstname, ваше сообщение было успешно отправленно.";

Comment: Дайте вашему инпуту (который type = send) name = "button", должно заработать

Comment: Увы, письма все равно не приходят. Хостинг показывает что отправлено 0 писем из 500 за сутки.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/KXjdR

Comment: @user234223 Попробуйте сделать var_dump  (mail ($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders));

Comment: Та же ерунда :c